# C++11 lambdas passed as std::function params - dispatching on return type

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11, std-function

The scenario:

We have an API that has a generic error handling interface. It is a C API, so it tells us that after every API function called, we need to execute some boilerplate like this:

```
if (APIerrorHappened()) {
    APIHandle h;
    while(h = APIgetNextErrorContext(...)) {
       cerr << APIgetText(h) << endl;
    }
}
```

You obviously hate repeating yourself, so you want to encapsulate this handling in a macro that allows you to write code like this:

```
...
// this API call returns something
APItype foo = MYMACRO(APIsomeFunction1(...));
// this one doesn't
MYMACRO(APIsomeFunction2(...));
// neither does this (glCompileShader)
MYMACRO(APIsomeFunction3(...));
...
```

You can also think of this in terms of aspect-oriented programming - imagine that the macro adds logging, sends info to remote monitor, whatever... The point is that it is supposed to encapsulate an expression, do whatever **around** it, and return whatever type the expression returns - and of course the expression may not return *anything*.

Which means you can't just do

```
#define MYMACRO(x) { auto x = expr(); ... }
```

...because in some cases, the expression doesn't return anything!

So... How would you do that?

Please don't suggest encapsulating the complete statement inside the macro...

```
#define MYMACRO(x)       \
{                        \
   /* ... stuff ...   */ \
   x;                    \
   // ... stuff
}
```

...since this would never work for stuff like:

```
if (foo() || APIfunctionReturningBool(...) || bar()) {
     ...
     APIfunction1();
     ...
} else if (APIOtherfunctionReturningBool() || baz()) {
     ...
     APIfunction2();
     ...
}
```

...you engulf all the if statement? Its actions include other API calls, so... macro within macro? Debugging just became hell.

My own attempt is below, using lambdas and std::function - but it is arguably, ugly...
I could not pass a lambda of the expression directly to a template that takes std::function (to specialize based on the lambda's return type), so the code turned out rather nasty.

Can you think of a better way?

```
void commonCode(const char *file, size_t lineno) {
    // ... error handling boilerplate
    // ... that reports file and lineno of error
}

template <class T>
auto MyAPIError(std::function<T()>&& t, const char *file, size_t lineno) -> decltype(t()) {
    auto ret = t();
    commonCode(file,lineno);
    return ret;
}

template<>
void MyAPIError(std::function<void(void)>&& t, const char *file, size_t lineno) {
    t();
    commonCode(file,lineno);
}

template <class T>
auto helper (T&& t) -> std::function<decltype(t())()>
{
    std::function<decltype(t())()> tmp = t;
    return tmp;
}

#define APIERROR( expr ) \
    return MyAPIError( helper( [&]() { return expr; } ),  __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

**UPDATE, an addendum to KennyTM's excellent solution**

I placed the actual OpenGL code that triggered this question [here](http://pastebin.com/fA4qZaaB). As you can see, the error checking code did more than just print - it also threw an exception that the user code could then handle. I am adding this addendum to note that with KennyTM's solution, you end up throwing this exception from a destructor, and that this is OK (read on):

```
struct ErrorChecker { 
    const char *file; 
    size_t lineno; 
    ~ErrorChecker() { 
        GLenum err = glGetError(); 
        if (err != GL_NO_ERROR) { 
            while (err != GL_NO_ERROR) { 
                std::cerr <<  
                    "glError: " << (char *)gluErrorString(err) <<  
                    " (" << file << ":" << lineno << ")" << std::endl; 
                err = glGetError(); 
            } 
            throw "Failure in GLSL..."; 
        } 
    } 
};
```

The reason it is OK to throw from this destructor, is explained in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9):

> The C++ rule is that you must never throw an exception from a destructor that is being called during the "stack unwinding" process of another exception... you can say never throw an exception from a destructor **while processing another exception**.

In our case, we want the user code (that calls the special macro) to handle the exception; so we need to know for certain that our "throw" in the ErrorChecker's destructor is the first one - i.e. that the actual C API called can never throw. This is easily accomplished with this form:

```
#define GLERROR(...)                                    \
    ([&]() -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__)                     \
    {                                                   \
        ErrorChecker _api_checker {__FILE__, __LINE__}; \
        (void) _api_checker;                            \
        try {                                           \
            return __VA_ARGS__;                         \
        } catch(...) {}                                 \
    } ())
```

This form of the macro guarantees that the actual C API (called via **VA_ARGS**) will never throw - and therefore, the "throw" in ErrorChecker's destructor will always be the **first one** doing it.

So this solution covers all angles of my original question - many thanks to [Alexander Turner](http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2012/03/c11-generic-error-catcher.html) for providing it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9625526/373025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the logging code to a destructor of some class ­— assuming the logger won't throw — and then create an instance of that class in the macro. Abusing the comma operator, we have:

```
struct Logger
{
    const char* file;
    int lineno;
    ~Logger()
    {
        // The APIerrorHappened stuff.
    }
};

#define APIERROR(...) (Logger{__FILE__, __LINE__}, (__VA_ARGS__))
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/CiLGR

Comment: you already commented on it, but what if the error handler throws? We can't throw from within Logger's destructor - any thoughts on how to cope with that?

Comment: @ttsiodras : You can pass `Logger`'s constructor a callback that should be invoked in case of exception; the destructor would invoke that inside of a try/catch. Of course, that callback should be noexcept as well.

Comment: @ttsiodras: Your code works when `commonCode` throws (but won't work when `expr` throws). Could you make that `commonCode` `noexcept`?

Comment: @KennyTM: Given the fact that commonCode is doing error handling, it is quite normal for it to report the error in stderr, and then throw an exception... Here is the [actual code](http://pastebin.com/fA4qZaaB) I had in mind (OpenGL stuff)