# How to view datatype of Auto in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

In visual studio, you can hover over the Auto datatype and see what datatype the compiler chooses for it. I haven't found a way to do this in xcode and would like to because with some of the larger code bases I have been working in, it becomes a point of confusion.

Comment: Option+click (Alt+click)

Comment: You might also be able to use `typeid().name()` if you want the type at run time

Comment: Top tip: if using `auto` makes it hard to know what type something is, and you need to know what type the thing is, you shouldn't be using `auto` in that place.

Comment: Top tip #2: if you need an IDE feature to understand your code, the code requires simplifying and/or more comments.

Comment: @Yonat - option+click opens a box that says No Quick Help, with a button to search documentation.

Comment: I'm using something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339450/8494588 to display some types oft interest in a compiler error.

Comment: It's a kludge, but I typically add the line `int i = autovariable;`. This generates an error about being unable to convert from Foo to int, so now I know that `auto` evaluated to `Foo`

Comment: @EdwardFalk Brilliant kludge