# Template type deduction of const reference type

Tags: c++, function-templates, const-reference

It is a bit confusing to me about how C++ 11 does template deduction when const references to a template parameter types are used. Consider the following program:

```
template <typename T> void test_func(const T &a){
    (*a)++; 
}

int main() {
    // 1st case
    int i = 1;
    test_func(&i); 
    
    // 2nd case
    const int* cPtr = &i; 
    test_func(cPtr); 
}
```

My questions are:

- For the first case, it is compiled fine; so it seems like the instantiated template function parameter is `int* const &a` (a top-level const); but if we directly replace `T with` int*`, we get` const int* &a` (a low-level const) and compiler should have failed; how can we express a low-level const in a format of "const T &a"; I am confused what is the real type of the parameter and what is the type of T;
- For the second case, compilation fails with an

  ```
  error: increment of read-only location `*(const int*)a;'
  ```

  It  seems like the second instantiated function inherits the low-level const as well; then what is the type of parameter; what is the type of `T`;

Comment: `const T &a` is clearly "a const reference to T". Wouldn't it be very strange and surprising if passing `const int*` as `T` and suddenly you would get "a non-const reference to T where T is `const int*`"? I would find that very counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Your `test_func()` receives a const reference to something.  In the first case, the something is the address of an integer, so the final type is "a reference which cannot be used to change its referent which is a pointer to an integer."  This means you can use the pointer to the integer, including using it to change the integer, but you cannot change the value of the pointer (i.e. the address) to point to something else.

In the second case the final type is "a reference which cannot be used to change its referent which is a pointer to an integer and the pointer cannot be used to change the integer."  Therefore, `*a` is `const int` which cannot be modified.

Answer (score 2):

#### First case

> if we directly replace `T` with `int*`, we get `const int* &a` (a low-level const) and the compiler should have failed.

Not really...

The thing is, C++ (following C) has a somewhat convoluted syntax for declaring variables, "directly-replacing" doesn't mean "simple copy-pasting". In your case, let's suppose you rewrite your declaration as `T const&`. Now if you copy-paste you get:

```
void test2(int * const &a){
    (*a)++; 
}
```

which should compile just fine, and does.

#### Second case

> what is the type of T?

Let's check! Following an answer to this question: [Print template typename at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9813316/1593077)

we write:

```
template <typename T> void test_func(T const &a){
    bool x = T::nothing; 
    (*a)++; 
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    // 2nd case
    const int* cPtr = &i; 
    test_func(cPtr);     
}
```

and when we [run this program](https://godbolt.org/z/b34a3M), we get:

```
source>: In instantiation of 'void test_func(const T&) [with T = const int*]':
<source>:10:19:   required from here
<source>:2:17: error: 'nothing' is not a member of 'const int*'
    2 |     bool x = T::nothing;
      |                 ^~~~~~~
```

so, `T` is `const int*` for this case.

Comment: is `T const &` preferred in declaration than `const T &`? I understand it is low-level const in the format of 'T const &';

Comment: No, neither is preferred. Or rather - it's a "religious" debate... see also: [Const before or const after?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5503352/1593077). As for "low-level const" - there is no such term. That is, I've never heard of it. The question is only what construct the const applies to. The C grammar is a bit confusing with its rule; and you can't always clarify with (parentheses), since those are also used to declare a function.

Comment: Umm, I quoted "low-level const" from C++ primer, see this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/143366/; now, my problem is more about the format; this may not make sense at all; but my question is: if in the template, we declare parameter in the format of `const T &`, how it can become `int* const &`? Those two forms does not match.

Comment: Just don't think of template instantiation as purely copy-pasing of text. The template type is "A reference to a constant T". If T is "a pointer to int", then the instantiated template is "A reference to a constant pointer-to-int". As though the T is "boxed".

Comment: @Marcus_Ma: Ok, I take back my earlier comment. Apparently one of these terms was officially introduced into the standard for C++17. They're still rarely used in my experience.

Comment: got it! Thanks very much for your explanation!

Comment: @Marcus_Ma: On Stackoverflow, the way to thank people is by accepting their answer or upvoting - that's all the thanks we need.