# Get name of type behind type alias in function template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013.

When I need to know what types the compiler deduced for my template parameters, I usually trigger a compiler error like this:

```cpp
template <typename U>
struct TD;

template <typename T>
void f(T) {
    TD<T> t{};
}

int main() {
    f(1);
}
```

And this works, as Visual Studio will tell me I tried to instanciate my undefined `struct TD` with an `int`:

```
error C2079: 't' uses undefined struct 'TD<T>'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void f<int>(T)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
```

However, the above trick becomes useless on Visual Studio if I want to know what's the type behind a type alias. E.g. the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T) {
    using unsigned_int_t = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
    TD<unsigned_int_t> t{};
}
```

will produce:

```
error C2079: 't' uses undefined struct 'TD<unsigned_int_t>'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void f<int>(T)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
```

Whereas GCC will tell me that `unsigned_int_t` is a `unsigned int`:

```
error: 'TD<unsigned int> t' has incomplete type
   10 |     TD<unsigned_int_t> t{};
```

So, is there a way to get the name of the type behind a type alias with Visual Studio 2013?

**Note:** I already had a look at [Print template typename at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813316/print-template-typename-at-compile-time) but no answer worked for me.

Comment: The `T` in the MSVC error message is the `T` in the `f` template, not the `T` in the `TD` template. Would be clearer if you renamed one of the template arguments. This is what it has always been.

Comment: I've updated my question and changed `T` in `TD` to `U` so that maybe it's a bit clearer. However, VS would still tell me that the `T` I (try) instanciate `TD` with is actually an `int`, which is what I want to know.

Comment: My trick is `template<typename U> void whatis();` followed by `whatis<unsigned_int_t>();` produces "unresolved reference to void whatis<unsigned int>(void)".

Comment: Thanks, @Raymond. Moving the error from compile to link time is certainly a good solution (please consider posting your comment as an answer). Do you know if there's a compile-time error I could trigger that would produce the information I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [typeid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/typeid-operator?view=msvc-170) (The typeid operator allows the type of an object to be determined at run time). Try the snippet below:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <typeinfo> 
using namespace std;
template <typename U>
struct TD {};

//template <typename T>
//void f(T) {
//    TD<T> t{};
//}
template <typename T>
void f(T) {
    using unsigned_int_t = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
    TD<unsigned_int_t> t{};
     cout<<typeid(t).name();

}

int main()
{
    f(1);
}
```

Output:

```
struct TD<unsigned int>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work as `typeid` will ignore references. Here's an example from the bottom of the page you linked: `typeid(int) == typeid(int&)` (evaluates to true).