# Getting rid of references in an boost::fusion sequence

Tags: c++, templates, boost, reference, boost-fusion

I'm trying to use Boost::Fusion to transform a list of function's parameter types into a fusion::list. Ultimately, I am trying to turn a list of variables into parameters that I can call a function with (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164914/generating-wrappings-for-c-functions).

I've gotten this to work for non-referenced variables. However, it fails to compile for non-referenced variables when I try to turn the function's parameter list (specifically on the fusion::to_list it complains it can't deref the iterator).

I've simplified the code down by a bit below:

```
struct identity {
  template<typename Sig> struct result;

  template <typename T>
  struct result<convert(T)> { typedef T type; };

  template <typename T>
  typename T operator ()(T) const { 
     return T();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(foo) params_type;
  auto seq = function_types::parameter_types<params_type>();
  auto transformed = fusion::transform(seq, identity());
  auto passedParams = fusion::as_list(transformed);
}
```

If foo is defined as:

```
int foo(int a) { return 5*a; }
```

it works fine, but it breaks on:

```
int foo(int &a) { return 5*a; }
```

For the purposes of my code, I don't actually need the references kept in the sequence, which I am assuming is the issue (also, searches I've done tend to point that as being the culprit). However, I'm not completely sure of how to strip the `transformed` function of these references before `as_list` is called.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
struct result<convert(T)>: remove_reference<T> {};

template <typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type operator ()(remove_reference<T>::type) const { return typename remove_reference<T>::type(); }
```

but got the same compile errors.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

**update**

Here is the truncated compiler error I get (with clang++ --std=c++0x) for both cases given above:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/mpl/mpl_iterator.hpp:43:24: error: 
      reference to type 'int' requires an initializer
                return type();
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/fusion/iterator/deref.hpp:61:28: note: in instantiation
  of member function
  'boost::fusion::mpl_iterator<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::function_types::parameter_types<void
  (int &), boost::add_reference<mpl_::arg<-1> > >, 0>
  >::deref<boost::fusion::mpl_iterator<boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::function_types::parameter_types<void
  (int &), boost::add_reference<mpl_::arg<-1> > >, 0> > >::call' requested
  here
    return deref_meta::call(i);

...

test4.cpp:65:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
  'boost::fusion::as_list<boost::fusion::transform_view<const
  boost::function_types::parameter_types<void (int &),
  boost::add_reference<mpl_::arg<-1> > >, convert, boost::fusion::void_> >'
  requested here
    auto passedParams = fusion::as_list(transformed);
```

Comment: If you get compilation errors, it would be a good idea to edit your question to include them.

Comment: Will do -- I avoided doing so because it's template error and therefore long and difficult to parse. Because of that I included (above) the final error the compiler gives (when calling as_list in deref_impl).

Comment: Ok, I added an abbreviated form of the error. I can include more if it helps, the trace runs through: defer.hpp -> defer_impl.hpp -> defer.hpp -> build_cons.hpp -> convert.hpp -> test4.cpp

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler is C++11 compatible, you might want to look into the [`std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) function. Or at least try to find an implementation of it and use as reference for making your own.

Comment: I did try remove_reference (see above), but might not have applied it correctly. Can you give any example of applying it to a fusion view?