# How do I convert a function wrapper in to templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have several very similar functions:

```
v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudioPlay(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) audio->play(get(args[0], 0));
    return args.This();
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudioPause(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) audio->pause();
    return args.This();
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudioLoop(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) audio->loop(get(args[0], -1));
    return args.This();
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudioVolume(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) audio->volume(get(args[0], 1.0f));
    return args.This();
}
```

And I've been reading about C++ templates for hours and I'm convinced that it's possible to get rid of these functions and replace them with templates. I envision the end result will be something like:

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*InvocationCallback)(const Arguments& args);

template <class T> InvocationCallback FunctionWrapper ...;
template <class T> FunctionWrapper FunctionReal ...;
template <class T, class arg1> FunctionWrapper FunctionReal ...;
template <class T, class arg1, class arg2> FunctionWrapper FunctionReal ...;
```

I realize similar questions have been asked, but I can't find an example of a template within a template like the above.

---

**Update on 7/21/2012**

Template:

```
template <class T> v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) t->volume(args[0]->NumberValue());
    return args.This();
}
```

Usage:

```
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Volume", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio>));
```

Now if I could only figure out how to pass `&Audio::volume` to the template, I'll be in business.

---

**Update on 7/24/2012**

Refer to my answer for how I solved this.

Comment: Same general idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625526/check-at-compile-time-if-template-argument-is-void), it ends up being called like `wrap (someFunc, arg1, arg2, arg3)`. I hope that at least gives a start.

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using? Specifically, can you use C++11?

Comment: gcc (Gentoo 4.5.3-r2 p1.1, pie-0.4.7) 4.5.3 -- How can I determine if I can use C++11?

Comment: @Caleb : You can use the subset of C++11 features listed [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for versions < 4.6.

Comment: What's the point of the template parameter `T`? You only seem to need to instantiate it with `Audio` as the template argument, so why bother parametrising it on that type? You want a function template that can call different functions, but always for `Audio`, right?

Comment: No, there are several classes like this: Audio, Material, Mesh, etc. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Templates:

```
template <class T, class RT, RT(T::*f)()> v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) (t->*f)();
    return args.This();
}
template <class T, class RT, class A0, RT(T::*f)(A0)> v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) (t->*f)(jsConvert<A0>(args[0]));
    return args.This();
}
template <class T, class RT, class A0, class A1, RT(T::*f)(A0, A1)> v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsFunctionTemplate(const v8::Arguments &args) {
    T *t = static_cast<T*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (t != NULL) (t->*f)(jsConvert<A0>(args[0]), jsConvert<A1>(args[1]));
    return args.This();
}
```

Usage:

```
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Play", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, Audio*, int, &Audio::play>));
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Pause", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, Audio*, &Audio::pause>));
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Loop", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, Audio*, int, &Audio::loop>));
audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Volume", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, Audio*, float, &Audio::volume>));
```

Now I need to figure out the two final steps: variable number of arguments, and properly templating `jsConvert` to return the desired type `<A0>`.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the magic of the lambda.

```
template<typename F> v8::Handle<v8::Value> jsAudio(const v8::Arguments &args, F&& f) {
    Audio *audio = static_cast<Audio*>(args.This()->GetPointerFromInternalField(0));
    if (audio != NULL) f(audio, args);
    return args.This();
}
int main() {
    jsAudio(..., [&](Audio* audio, const v8::Arguments &args) {
        audio->play(get(args[0], 0));
    });
}
```

For example.

Comment: While this definitely put me on the right track, is it possible to make this even more generic? I'm using these templates as a callback: `audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Play", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsAudioPlay));` so they need to hold their `InvocationCallback` type... I'm hoping for the code to look something like this: `audio->PrototypeTemplate()->Set("Play", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(jsFunctionTemplate<Audio, Audio::play>));` I can figure out what to do with a variable number of args later.

Comment: @CalebGray, define "more generic".  That function is pretty generic, it can be passed any callable object, such as a lambda, or `bind(&Audio::play, _1, bind(&get, bind(&Args::operator[], _2, 0), 0))` or `bind(&Audio::pause, _1)` or a `function<void(Audio&, const Arguments&)>` or a suitable functor etc.

Comment: The thing is, I need to pass the result as a pointer to a function: `v8::FunctionTemplate::New(&jsFunctionTemplate<Audio>)` and, as far as I can tell, this answer changes the function's decltype and so it breaks my ability to use it as a callback. Refer to my answer for my current solution.