# Generic function implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a new platform and my code is:

### Layer1:

```
Call_To_Layer2 (param1, param2);
```

### Layer2:

```
Call_To_Layer2(param1, param2)
{
    Dispatch_Work_To_Thread(param1, param2);
}

Dispatch_Work_To_Thread(param1, param2)
{
    // create a new thread and execute the task
}
```

The function call from Layer1 can have any number of parameters. So how can I design such a method in Layer2?
Dispatch_Work_To_Thread method in layer2 requires the function name as one of the parameters. Since the number of parameters is not constant, how can this be designed?

I have pondered about the design for this problem, but couldn't come up with any solution till now.

Comment: I don't know quite how much it'll help, but I had something working that could call any function with the arguments passed in (e.g. something like `wrap(std::pow, 2.5, 3);`). The whole `void` business was so that I could store the return value only if it had one. Anyway, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625526/check-at-compile-time-if-template-argument-is-void

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have `Call_To_Layer2` and `Dispatch_Work_To_Thread` take an [`std::function<void(void)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and create the function object out of any function name and parameters.

Layer1 functions:

```
void foo_layer1(param1, param2);
void bar_layer1(param1, param2);
```

Layer 2:

```
#include <functional>

Call_To_Layer2 (std::function<void(void)> f); // or reference_wrapper to std::function

f00 = std::bind(foo_layer1, param1, param2);
Call_To_Layer2(foo);  // passes it on to `Dispatch_Work_To_Thread`
```

If you don't have the required C++11 support, you could use [boost.function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function.html) and [boost.bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe put all the parameters in a struct or a class, and pass an object to `Call_To_Layer2`? This would work if the class can encapsulate the variable factor.
2. One other option is to use the variadic function syntax `Call_To_Layer2(param1, param2, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific example it's difficult to know what the best solution is.

[Variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D) might be one option, although they are mostly considered antiquated these days.

The easiest might be to simply wrap the arguments in a `std::vector` or similar, and let the layer 2 code unpack them as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be done portably with C++. You can however change things a little and having your functions accepting a single parameter that is a map containing all the relevant parameters:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Anything> Parms;

Anything function1(const Parms& parms)
{
    double x = parms("x");
    std::string title = parms("title");
    ...
}

void init_module()
{
    register_function("function1", function1,
                      "void return, double x, string title");
}
```

In the above example `Anything` is a class that can contain any of the types you want to support as parameters or return values. I am used to code it myself but probably `boost::any` is ok for that.
Every published function accepts only a dictionary of parameters and the function publishes also the return type and parameters. This information is stored in a map for dispatching and parameter checking so that you don't need to code checking in all functions and also allows publishing directory services.

You could also use instances of classes that implements a "call" method instead of functions for the published services (this is what I'm used to do).

Unfortunately C++ design is not very compatible with this use case and a lot of coding is required. There is no such a thing like "call the function with this name passing these parameters" where the function name and parameters are provided at runtime.

Note that this use is on the other hand not so uncommon and therefore you can find a lot of libraries that try to add this dinamicity to C++... how they fit to your exact problem, what dependencies they have and how complex they are is something that must be considered.